# Duplicate timestamps in elasticbeanstalk logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Java SE based application in AWS ElasticBeanstalk. The application logs go to the standard /var/logs/web.stdout.log file. From there they are streamed to Cloudwatch and then to Opensearch. The issue is that the logs in Cloudwatch have duplicate timestamps.

```
2022-07-10T13:00:24.248-07:00 Jul 10 20:00:19 ip-172-31-3-142 web: 20:00:19.401 "Some application log message"
```

The outermost one (2022-07-10T13 ...) is (I think) added by the cloudwatch agent running in my EC2 instance. This is also the one used by Opensearch

The second one (Jul 10 20:00:19 ...) seems to be added by the elastic beanstalk Java SE configuration.

The innermost one (web: 20:00:19.401) is added by my application logger (logback). This is one that I want to be used both in Cloudwatch and Opensearch.  How do I change the Beanstalk Java SE config and the Cloudwatch agent config to use this timestamp and get rid of the other two?